# Calling Serverside method within Client Side Function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, client, client-side, serverside-javascript

can anyone help me in calling my VB.NET method within my javascript function? my method is not shared/static and does not return anything. It just simply saves data to database and redirect the user. PLease help me, Here's my code:

VB method

```
  Public Function SaveVehicles()
          Dim res As Boolean
             If res = True Then
            Dim sModel As String = cboModel.SelectedValue
            Dim sVariant As String = cboVariant.SelectedValue
            Dim sColor As String = cboColor.SelectedValue

            cboModel.SelectedValue = sModel
            cboVariant.SelectedValue = sVariant
            cboColor.SelectedValue = sColor


            Dim oData As New WebServVehSwapping
            Dim strSql As String
            Dim sDealer As String
            Dim sUserName As String

            'sDealer = "TBP01"
            sDealer = Trim(Request.QueryString("dealercode"))
            If sDealer = "" Then sDealer = "TBP01"
            sUserName = "User1"

            '------------------------------------------
            strSql = oData.InsertTblRequirement( _
              sDealer _
             , Now.ToString _
             , sUserName _
             , cboColor.Text.Trim _
             , cboModel.Text.Trim _
             , cboVariant.Text.Trim, "Open")
            MsgBox("OKAY")
            Response.Redirect("MyRequirements.aspx?DealerCode=" & sDealer)
        Else
            'do Nothing
        End If
    End Function
```

and here's my Javascript function

```
   function ConfirmView()
    {   
        var Ok = confirm('There is/are existing vehicle(s) in Network Vehiches for sale, View Vehicle(s)?');
        if(Ok==true)
        {

       location.href = 'NetworkVehiclesforSale.aspx';
        return false;
        }
        else if (Ok!=true)
        {

         //THE VB METHOD GOES HERE     
      }
}
```

I've tried the callback handler, and it just works with function that return something/string

and i've tried Pagemethod but it just works with static/shared function. please help me, I really need it Badly. PLEasee. Thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, I'd appreciate it if you'd consider marking it as an answer, or asking a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read "Introduction to Building Windows Communication Foundation Services" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480190.aspx

And especially: "A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5" - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx

And check out some javascript libraries that make calling RESTful web services easy, like jQuery - http://www.jquery.com/

With jQuery you could make a call to your server-side VB.NET code like this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "GET",  
    contentType: 'text/json',  
    dataType: 'json',  
    url: "https://URL-TO-SERVICE-HERE/...",  
    timeout: 10000,  
    error: function () {  

        // Deal with the error  

    },  
    success: function (data) {  

        // Do something with the result
        // Example:
        if (data.dealerCode) 
            location.href = 'MyRequirements.aspx?DealerCode=' + data.dealerCode;


    }  
});
```

Comment: and in what part of this code i can call the SaveVehicles() method?

Comment: You'd place this javascript snippet where you wrote "//THE VB METHOD GOES HERE" in your question. You'd change "URL-TO-SERVICE-HERE" in the snippet to point at your .svc file (WCF service) - which will run your "SaveVehicles()" method.

Answer (score 1):

.Net web services cannot perform magic, i.e. you cannot issue a redirect response to an Ajax request on the server and expect the whole page to be redirected.
The only thing that will happen is that the Ajax call got redirected to another page and tries to get data from there. If you want to change the page in the client browser, you must do it on the client side through JavaScript, e.g. `document.location = url_returned_by_your_function_through_ajax_call`.

Comment: how about how can i call the SaveVehicles() method?